# Data objects unicode in popup ABAP

Tags: abap

I have the next problem to show a popup AVL. My error is the next:
**The statement**
"MOVE src TO dst"
requires that the operands "dst" and "src" are convertible.
Since this statement is in a Unicode program, the special conversion
rules for Unicode programs apply.
In this case, these rules were violated.
**My code is the next:**

```
TYPES:
  BEGIN OF ty_posic,
    ebelp   TYPE EKPO-EBELP,
    posid   TYPE PRPS-POSID,
    texto   TYPE PRPS-POST1,
    impor   TYPE NETPR,
    waers   TYPE EKKO-WAERS,
  END OF ty_posic.
* Tablas internas.
DATA:
  t_posic   TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ty_posic,
  t_cols    TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF help_value,
  t_tabix   TYPE sy-tabix,
  t_just    TYPE CATSXT_LONGTEXT_ITAB.
* Workareas.
DATA:
  wa_cols   LIKE LINE OF t_cols,
  wa_posic  LIKE LINE OF t_posic.

..........

  CLEAR t_tabix.
  APPEND wa_cols TO t_cols.
    wa_cols-tabname    = 'EKPO'.
    wa_cols-fieldname  = 'EBELP'.
    wa_cols-selectflag = 'X'.
  APPEND wa_cols TO t_cols.
    wa_cols-tabname    = 'PRPS'.
    wa_cols-fieldname  = 'POSID'.
  APPEND wa_cols TO t_cols.
    wa_cols-tabname    = 'PRPS'.
    wa_cols-fieldname  = 'POST1'.
  APPEND wa_cols TO t_cols.
    wa_cols-tabname    = 'EKPO'.
    wa_cols-fieldname  = 'NETPR'.
  APPEND wa_cols TO t_cols.
    wa_cols-tabname    = 'EKKO'.
    wa_cols-fieldname  = 'WAERS'.
  APPEND wa_cols TO t_cols.

  CALL FUNCTION 'MD_POPUP_SHOW_INTERNAL_TABLE'
  EXPORTING
    title   = 'My text'
  IMPORTING
    index   = t_tabix 
  TABLES
    values  = t_posic
    columns = t_cols
  EXCEPTIONS
    leave   = 1
    others  = 2.
...........
```

Greethings!

Comment: Please add a minimal working example, not just some random excerpt of your code, and state the actual error message including the field names.

Comment: Where is exactly the error raised? This sample runs perfectly well for me.

Comment: Only a portion of the program is shown, what are the attributes of the dst field? Appending an empty row as the first row in table T_COLS. Why? What's being passed in T_POSIC to the FM.  Where are you getting an error? Look at one of the ALV demo programs SALV_DEMO_TABLE_POPUP or SALV_DEMO* There is a Wiki for ABAP program demo'ing popups in a program.... There is an SAP Help for ABAP and Unicode